# Print Nested GraphQL Data in a RSS Feed using Javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, graphql

I'm trying to build a RSS feed from my Contentful GraphQL Data. I'm using this tutorial to build the RSS feed: https://www.contentful.com/blog/2021/03/05/generate-blog-rss-feed-with-javascript-and-netlify/.

This query here work in the GraphQL playground:

```
query {
  sourcePostCollection(limit: 1) {
    items {
      sys {
        id
      }
      postTracksCollection(limit: 5) {
        items {
          name
          author
          genre
          bpm
        }
      }
      postSourcesCollection(limit: 5) {
        items {
          linkTitle
          linkUrl
          linkType
          linkOwner
          authorName
          authorWebsite
          linkFeatured
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

When its time to print the "postTracksCollection name"

```
function buildRssItems(items) {
  const truncateLength = 44;

  return items
    .map((item) => {
      return `
        <item>
          <name>${item.postTracksCollection.items.name}</name>
        </item>
        `;
    })
    .join("");
}
```

It returns undefined in the RSS feed
[image: RSS Feed]

I'm pretty sure I'm missing something either here in this part of the code:

```
let posts = "";

const req = https.request(options, (res) => {
  res.on("data", (data) => {
    posts += data;
  });

  res.on("end", () => {
    const parsedPosts = JSON.parse(posts);
    resolve(parsedPosts.data.sourcePostCollection.items);
  });
});

req.on("error", (e) => {
  console.error(e);
});

req.write(JSON.stringify({ query }));
req.end();
```

or i'm not writing the way to print nested items right. Any thoughts?

---

Update:

So I'm trying to build my RSS feed to match this email design Im working on. The goal is to take my contentful post (which gathers multiple post types together), create an RSS feed from that post. Then Mailchimp reads the latest RSS feed, and creates an email post to send to my subscribers.

[image: bbxemail]

As you see, I just need:

1. Track name
2. Track genre
3. Source name
4. Source URL

Comment: 1st `items` is an array ... nested `items` is an array, too ;)

Comment: @xadm, so would I do another one of these to access it?:

res.on("end", () => {
    const parsedPosts = JSON.parse(posts);
    resolve(parsedPosts.data.postTracksCollection.items);
  });

Comment: check data shape first `<name>${JSON.stringify(item)}` ... if you want to 'skip' (not render) this depth level ... full 'path' is required ... ... data.sourcePC...items[0].postTC...items

Comment: @xadm Is there a chance I can pay you to do this for me? Im a business person first, developer second, lol.

Comment: :D `resolve(parsedPosts.data.sourcePostCollection.items[0].postTracksCollection.items);` and in render just `<name>{$item.name}</name>` - assuming you want ro render tracks only

Comment: @xadm Thank you! Ok I got somewhere. It's showing the track name. I tried to add the genre, but I got an error. If I view the source of the RSS feed, it shows everything the right way.

Now if I want to get sourcePostCollection items (like the sys id), postTracksCollection items and postSourcesCollection items, would I basically need to rewrite how I'm mapping everything?

Comment: what data/elements and where in rss tree you want them, what is expected result ... update the question

Comment: Added update @xadm

Comment: rss is a 'flat' format ... by joining 2 arrays with 5 items you're getting one array with 10 elements ... it's doable with this datasource ... but .. IDK if mailchimp will be able to recognize two datasets and display them in two-part template ... maybe with 2 different feeds?

Comment: @xadm, hmm interesting. So I would need to simplify my datasource. Interesting. Thanks for this.